# How to scan Beacons in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

I am developing an app to search nearest beacon device but not able to calling any delegate, Already I have beacons available but not finding any beacons.

Also I did not understand `NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"3863C90B-1BA6-4A4E-ADD2-D64FF1286898"];` is static is passed or not?

```
 NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"3863C90B-1BA6-4A4E-ADD2-D64FF1286898"];
    self.myBeaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid
                                                             identifier:@"com.jss.myidentifire"];

    self.myBeaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = YES;
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    [locationManager requestStateForRegion:region];
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    if (state == CLRegionStateInside)
    {
        [self locationManager:locationManager didEnterRegion:region];
    }

}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    // We entered a region, now start looking for our target beacons!
    self.statusLabel.text = @"Finding beacons.";
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"BeaconDetail" message:@"DidEnterRegion Called" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    // Exited the region
    self.statusLabel.text = @"None found.";
    [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"BeaconDetail" message:@"didExitRegion Called" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager
       didRangeBeacons:(NSArray*)beacons
              inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region
{
    self.statusLabel.text = @"Beacon found!";
    CLBeacon *foundBeacon = [beacons firstObject];
    NSString *uuid = foundBeacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString;
    NSString *major = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundBeacon.major];
    NSString *minor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundBeacon.minor];
    NSString *accuracy = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", foundBeacon.accuracy];
    accuracy = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", foundBeacon.accuracy];

    if (foundBeacon.proximity == CLProximityUnknown) {
        self.distanceLabel.text = @"Unknown Proximity";
    } else if (foundBeacon.proximity == CLProximityImmediate) {
        self.distanceLabel.text = @"Immediate";
    } else if (foundBeacon.proximity == CLProximityNear) {
        self.distanceLabel.text = @"Near";
    } else if (foundBeacon.proximity == CLProximityFar) {
        self.distanceLabel.text = @"Far";
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setObject:uuid forKey:@"uuid"];
    [dict setObject:major forKey:@"major"];
    [dict setObject:minor forKey:@"minor"];
    [dict setObject:accuracy forKey:@"accuracy"];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"BeaconDetail" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dict] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: please go thru [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AirLocate/Introduction/Intro.html) and a sample is also their

Comment: you are missing asking for authorization so this will definitely not work - also .. you don't show how you allocate the locationManager or set the delegate..

Comment: Ismail i have a iphone6+ device i have taken build from appleDocumentation still this build are not able to search beacons. i can broadcast my device but not able to find beacon from this source code.

Comment: hey daij-djan let forget about it.. can i get beacon without location service on? i mean then why we are using corebluetooth framework and why we are using BLE4.0 if we want to access location from the gps? if we are access location service on then we do not want BLE. right?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have obtained permission to scan for beacons by adding the following:

```
if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
```

For the above to work, you also need to add a new key to your Info.plist file: `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` with a value set to something like "This app wants to scan for beacons"

Answer (score -1):

if you start the receiver when it's already in the beacon range, it's not going to fire. Just checking that you're walking far away from the beacon and then walking back into range to get it to fire?

Comment: Is that really possible?I dont think so its possible. but i ll just check it out.

Comment: didDetermineState is being called at the beginning in that case

Comment: and ranging doesn't care about regions - op does both so... nah this isn't it